# How do I create a custom sort order in Salesforce Analytics Cloud

Tags: einstein-analytics, analytics

I'm just trying to create the custom sort order of the Opportunity pipeline stage in Salesforce analytics cloud. Can anyone tell me how to do this properly?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a bucket field using a recipe and assign the stages 1:1 and sort by that. However, it can only sort alphanumerically, so if its a completely custom sort, you might need to create a formula field in salesforce to assign them correctly.